# array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

Tags: php, arrays

I recently moved the cpanel hosting and I have the following error that I can not solve if you can help me. thank you

```
File: /public_html/admin/users.php
Line: 180
Message: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

Call stack:

File: /public_html/admin/users.php (Line: 180)
Function: array_keys
```

LINE 180:

```
 <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($recruits))); ?></th>
```

Comment: We need more information to be able to help you., Whats is in `$recruits`? What you get for the result of `var_dump($recruits)`?

Answer (score 0):

The error says itself. Aparently, you want to concatenate the array keys with `th` element, but please take a look at what `current` and `array_keys` actually does and requires to function properly, the documentation is self-explanatory but I'll write some examples below in hopes to help you understand.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

array_keys will extract the keys from an **Associative array**, e.g.:

```
$mySpecialArray = ["key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value 2"];
$keys = array_keys($mySpecialArray);
//$keys will contain "key1", "key2"

//I feel you're new to php, so I'm going to write an example of implode aswell

$implodeStringWithComma = implode(',', $keys);
//$implodeStringWithComma will result in a string like this -->  "key1,key2"

$implodeStringWithTh = implode('</th><th>', $keys)
//$implodeStringWithTh will result in a string like this -->  "key1</th><th>key2"
```

Your error states that what is inside the array_keys is not an array, that is because what is inside array_keys is  `current($recruits)` and the error is telling you that  `current($recruits)` is a boolean. So, what does current do?

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

"The current() function simply returns the value of the array element that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer.
**Warning**
This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. "

Without futher explanation on what's inside `$recruits` and the purpose, can't help you more, but I'm guessing you're going from result to result in `$recruits`. I believe the `$recruits` is an **Multidimensional array**, something among these lines:

```
$recruits[0] => ["key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2", "key3" => "value3"];
$recruits[1] => ["key4" => "value4", "key5" => "value5", "key6" => "value6"];
.
.  
.
```

And I'm also guessing you're using the internal pointer to loop from array to array (When you use current($recruits), it gives the equivalent of `$recruits[0]`, when you do `next($recruits)` and again `current($recruits)`, the current will give you the next array, equivalent of `$recruits[1]`, `end($recruits)` for example will give you the last array of `$recruits`). Most likely, your code is pointing (as documentation says) to something that is beyongdthe array, or the array being empty.